# Image not showing up on when using external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-gallery

I'm trying to implement a image gallery taken from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_gallery).
However, when I try to link the javascript externally, the first image won't show up. I'm not good at javascript so I'm having trouble fixing it. Here is my code in external file.

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       showSlides(slideIndex);
    });
    var slideIndex = 1;
    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("g-image-wrapper");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
      if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
      }
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
      captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
          <img src="img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
          <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
          <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
        </div>
        <div class="column"> 
          <img class="demo cursor" src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always include all the relevant code, including the HTML and CSS into a code snippet in your question so that we can replicate your issue and more easily provide you with an answer.

Comment: Additionally, have you looked at your developer console (press F12 in your browser) to see if there are any errors reported? And, it is well-known that W3 Schools is **not** a good resource to learn web development from as they often have incomplete, out of date, or flat out incorrect information. In your case, the use of inline styles, `.getElementsByClassName()`, and the `.className` property are all examples of "what not to do" these days as they are all out of date techniques.

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make the code runnable. Note that your title mentions "external JavaScript", but there is no reference to any external script in your HTML...

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, nothing wrong there. My problem here is that the first image is not showing up when it is loaded but its works fine if I press the next button. The thing is the image shows up if I write the javascript in the webpage but it doesn't work if I write the javascript in an external page.

Comment: Now that you have provided your code, you can see that you've got an error that needs to be addressed. If that is not the case in your actual project, then you haven't provided *all* the relevant code here.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the error? Can you point it to me?

Comment: Click the "Run" button at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I fixed it by writing another DOMContentLoaded, the error might have been fixed by that.